# Can I use filter in asp:repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Can I use filter in repeater if Yes than How? it is possible in asp.net c# ?

In my project I put the filter for dynamic data in repeater.

see the example i want that type of filter in Repeater [Click here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-filteringitem.html)

Comment: why dont you apply the filter before passing the collection to the control?

Comment: You can use dropdownlist bind to any field and on the basis of selected item from the list. you can filter the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

Since your repeater is bound to a DataSource, you should apply the filter condition to it.  For example, if the Datasource is represented by the SQLDataSource, please refer to the [SqlDataSource.FilterExpression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx) topic.  This appears to be a client side filtering.  If so the best solution would be to set the SQLDataSource.SelectCommand property so that it fetches required data from the DB.  This will reduce the data size transferred from the DB Server to the WebServer and make your application work faster.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to filter your data on the data source, how ever in repeater you can also filter them and show them or not as:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rMyID" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <% if (Condition) { %>
      Show this line
    <%} %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "filter" ?
I think you have to do it on your datasource.

Comment: filter means i can find out specific record from asp:repeater,database records bind in the repeater and i want to use filter for that record

Comment: So the filter must be execute within you database query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter in the browser, then you need to use JavaScript to show and hide the main element for each Item.

If you are filtering on the server, you need to do the filtering on the DataSource to remove the entries you don't want and DataBind() the Repeater each time this changes.
You can do the filtering manually using code, or use the FilterExpression if it is available as suggested by platon.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is using datatable filter property. Here is a simple example.

_dt = _dt.Select("COLUMN_NAME <> 'YOURFILTER'").CopyToDataTable();